# How to access xampp from another pc via LAN?

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp

I am running XAMPP on my windows 10. and installed WordPress site. All working fine on my pc and other PCs in my network.

I just changed my router.
My site is working on my PC but not working on other PCs.

When i connect with WiFi, its working. If i connect with cat5 wire, its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IP-Addresses and network configuration (e.g.: Gateway). Port Forwarding may also be needed on the new router.

For a better answer I'd need more details. For example, can you ping the other PCs on the network? Are you able to connect to the internet?

You should also check your firewall.